# When do votes to close/reopen expire?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I believe votes to close/reopen expire after some time.

When?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, close- / reopen votes do expire after some time. -- To cite the [help center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/close-questions):

> Close votes age away harmlessly after 4 days if the threshold is not reached.
>   Each new close vote resets the timer, and close votes only start expiring
>   [if the question has had 100 views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today/97594#97594).

Comment: For some more details see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away